# Why does this loop fail to get past my first MediaPlayer

Tags: android, loops, media-player, android-mediaplayer, playlist

I have 3 MediaPlayers: Track 0, Track 1, and Track 2. I want each track to start once the one before it finishes, and once that last track finishes, I want to go back to song 0 and start the cycle over. Here is the loop I made that is failing to do this:

```
public void myMusic() {
    while (y > 0) {
        music.get(track).start();

        if (music.get(track).isPlaying() == false) {
            music.get(track).stop();
            track++;

            if (track == 3) {
                track = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    try {
                        music.get(i).prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    music.get(i).seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        }
        y--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to close the first if block befor you check if track==3. But this is just a suggestion i dont try it.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I'd abandon the whole loop concept and go with an `OnCompletionListener`. Something like this might work -- I haven't tested this, just drew this out of my crazy head, but take it as conceptual:

```
private class LoopingCompletionListener implements OnCompletionListener {
    private int index;
    private int count;
    private int[] ids;
    private Resources res;

    public LoopingCompletionListener(int[] musicIds, Resources res) {
        //start on the second ID since you start the player with
        //the first one
        index = 1;
        count = musicIds.length();
        this.ids = ids;
        this.res = res;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Basically, just keep it between 0-2 -- this might need tweaking
        index = ((index + 2) % count) - 1;

        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(ids[index]);
        FileDescriptor fd = afd.getFileDescriptor();

        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(fd, afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
}

//Meanwhile, in onCreate()...
int[] musicIds = { R.raw.track01, R.raw.track02, R.raw.track03 };

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicIds[0]);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
        new LoopingCompletionListener(musicIds, getResources());
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, `isPlaying()` is only `false` when you set the MediaPlayer state to pause or stop.  In other words, you can't simply rely on it to determine when the music has reached the end of the stream to determine when it's done.

Also, from the documentation:

> Note that the transition from the Started state to the Paused state and vice versa happens asynchronously in the player engine. It may take some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying(), and it can be a number of seconds in the case of streamed content.

So it is an unreliable indicator for a use case such as this.

What you could do instead is take advantage of the `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`.  Register one for each MediaPlayer available whereby, upon completion, you advance to the next MediaPlayer.

So something like this:

```
public class PlayUponCompleteListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
   WeakReference<MediaPlayer> mNextPlayer;

   public PlayUponCompleteListener(MediaPlayer mp) {
     mNextPlayer = new WeakReference<MediaPlayer>(mp);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
     mp.stop();
     mp.reset();
     if(mNextPlayer.get() != null) {
       mNextPlayer.start();
     }
   }
}
```

Then, register them like so:

```
mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new CompletionListener(mp2));
mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new CompletionListener(mp3));
mp3.setOnCompletionListener(new CompletionListener(mp1));
```